# How to use Response property of controller class in static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I work on MVC5 project.

I have Login action method inside controller:

```
public void Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   string culture = getCulture();
   LocolizationCore.SetCulture(culture);
}
```

I have also in my project class named LocolizationCore and it contains static method named SetCulture().

Here how looks SetCulture() method:

```
    internal static void SetCulture(string culture)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

As you can see the SetCulture method is saving culture in user's cookies.

When I try to build the project I get error:

```
The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context    
The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context
```

My question is how to  use Response and Request properties in static method of the LocolizationCore class?

Comment: you need `HttpContext` reference in that class, do you have using statement in it for `System.Web.HttpContext` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the `HttpContext` to your static method `SetCulture`:

```
internal static void SetCulture(HttpContextBase httpContext, string culture)
{
    // use httpContext.Request or httpContext.Response here
}
```

Pass it in like this:

```
SetCulture(this.HttpContext, "culture")
```

Or:

```
SetCulture(HttpContext.Current, "culture")
```

Comment: Patrick,thanks for post.But on this parameter HttpContext.Current I get this error:

'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

it seems that Current property is missing.

Comment: Then omit `Current`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request` directly in your static class.

If you want to use an approach suggested by @Patrick Hofman you should wrap `HttpContext.Current` with `HttpContextWrapper` before passing it to the method:

```
SetCulture(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), "culture")
```

In the controller you have `Request` and `Response` properties. So I would suggest to pass those to your helper method.